# Parsing multiline logs : line + xml

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana, logstash-grok

I try to explain better:
I have this multiline log souce. 
Below I am showing a file with 3 logs, it is starting with "INFO" and finish with "</dialogue>":

```
INFO 05-01-16 08:06:01 [http-nio-8080-exec-8] (AbstractServer.java:454) -
<dialogue>
   <server>FirstLog</server>
   <duration>311</duration>
[...]
</dialogue>
INFO 05-01-16 08:06:02 [http-nio-8080-exec-8] (AbstractServer.java:454) -
<dialogue>
   <server>SecondLog</server>
   <duration>500</duration>
      [...]
</dialogue>
INFO 05-01-16 08:06:03 [http-nio-8080-exec-8] (AbstractServer.java:454) -
<dialogue>
   <server>ThirdLog</server>
   <duration>100</duration>
      [...]
</dialogue>
```

I am using this filter :

```
if [type] == "oldLogs" {
               multiline {
                  pattern => "^%{LOGLEVEL}"
                  what => "previous"
                  negate => "true"
               }    
               grok {
                   patterns_dir => "./patterns"
                   match => ["message", "(?m)%{LOGLEVEL:level} %{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:timestamp} \[%{PROG:msg_1}\] \(%{JAVAFILE:file}:%{NUMBER:line}\) \-%{GREEDYDATA:msg_3}"] 
                }   
                xml {
                     store_xml => "false"
                     source => "msg_3"
                     xpath =>[
                     "/dialogue/server/text()"  ,"server",  
                     "/dialogue/duration/text()"    ,"duration",
                     [...]
                  ]
                }
        }
```

then I am able to parse the JAVA logs and the xml.
But with my filters (post above) logstash is not able to undertand where is the end of my logs </dialogue>.

The output look like this :

```
"message" =><dialogue>\n<server>FirstLog</server>\n<duration>311</duration>\n[...]\n</dialogue>\nINFO 05-01-16 08:06:02 [http-nio-8080-exec-8] (AbstractServer.java:454) -\n<dialogue>\n<server>SecondLog</server>\n<duration>500</duration>\n[...]\n</dialogue>\nINFO 05-01-16 08:06:03 [http-nio-8080-exec-8] (AbstractServer.java:454) -\n<dialogue>\n<server>ThirdLog</server>\n<duration>100</duration>\n[...]\n</dialogue>
   "level" => "INFO",
   "timestamp" => "05-01-16 08:06:01",
   "msg_1" => "http-nio-8080-exec-8",
   "file" => "AbstractServer.java",
   "xmldata" => <dialogue>\n<server>FirstLog</server>\n<duration>311</duration>\n[...]\n</dialogue>\nINFO 05-01-16 08:06:02 [http-nio-8080-exec-8] (AbstractServer.java:454) -\n<dialogue>\n<server>SecondLog</server>\n<duration>500</duration>\n[...]\n</dialogue>\nINFO 05-01-16 08:06:03 [http-nio-8080-exec-8] (AbstractServer.java:454) -\n<dialogue>\n<server>ThirdLog</server>\n<duration>100</duration>\n[..]\n</dialogue>
   "server" => [ [0] "FirstLog" ],
   "duration" => [ [0] "311"
```

and logstash is parsing only the first xml log and is not considering the other 2. 
My final result should be:

```
{
   "message" => <dialogue>\n<server>FirstLog</server>\n<duration>311</duration>\n[...]\n</dialogue>
   "level" => "INFO",
   "timestamp" => "05-01-16 08:06:01",
   "msg_1" => "http-nio-8080-exec-8",
   "file" => "AbstractServer.java",
   "xmldata" => <dialogue>\n<server>FirstLog</server>\n<duration>311</duration>\n[...]\n</dialogue>
   "server" => [ [0] "FirstLog" ],
   "duration" => [ [0] "311"
}
{
   "message" => <dialogue>\n<server>SecondLog</server>\n<duration>500</duration>\n[...]\n</dialogue>
   "level" => "INFO",
   "timestamp" => "05-01-16 08:06:02",
   "msg_1" => "http-nio-8080-exec-8",
   "file" => "AbstractServer.java",
   "xmldata" =><dialogue>\n<server>SecondLog</server>\n<duration>500</duration>\n[...]\n</dialogue>
   "server" => [ [0] "SecondLog" ],
   "duration" => [ [0] "500"
}
{
   "message" => <dialogue>\n<server>ThirdLog</server>\n<duration>100</duration>\n[...]\n</dialogue>
   "level" => "INFO",
   "timestamp" => "05-01-16 08:06:03",
   "msg_1" => "http-nio-8080-exec-8",
   "file" => "AbstractServer.java",
   "xmldata" => <dialogue>\n<server>ThirdLog</server>\n<duration>100</duration>\n[...]\n</dialogue>
   "server" => [ [0] "ThirdLog" ],
   "duration" => [ [0] "100"
}
```

I hope this is clearer and someone has time to give me some more tips.

Regards

Comment: someone have any clue ?

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to join *all* the lines up into one with multiline (either the codec or filter, depending on your needs).

Then, grok out the log level, date, etc., and put the xml in a field of its own.

Finally, use the xml{} filter on your new xml field.

Comment: Thank you, I changed my filter
I is working quiet fine, gork and xml are parsing the line, but now I have a single line.
Now my logs become:
INFO 05-01-16 08:06:01 [http-nio-8080-exec-8] (AbstractServer.java:454) - \n<dialogue>\n<server>localhost</server>\n<duration>311</duration>\n[...]\n</dialogue>\nINFO 05-01-16 08:06:01 [http-nio-8080-exec-8] (AbstractServer.java:454) - \n<dialogue>\n<server>localhost</server>\n<duration>311</duration>\n[...]\n</dialogue>\n[...]

and I don't know how define the "end line", because above I have 2 different logs.
Regards

Comment: Update your posting with the new config.